# Font Awesome in eKoopmans / html2pdf.js did not show

Tags: font-awesome, html2pdf

I putted html2pdf.js  in my project,

https://github.com/eKoopmans/html2pdf.js .

And too I putted Font Awesome in my project,

Before pdf

[image: before pdf]

After pdf

[image: after pdf]

Why did not show the font awesome after output the pdf?

this is my codes

```
<script src="{{ asset('js/html2pdf.bundle.min.js') }}"></script>
<script>
    function generatePDF() {
        const element = document.getElementById("invoice");
        let opt = {
            filename:     'resume.pdf',
            image:        { type: 'jpeg', quality: 0.98 },
            jsPDF:        { unit: 'in', format: 'letter', orientation: 'portrait' }
        };
        html2pdf()
            .set(opt)
            .from(element)
            .save();
        {{--location.replace("{{route('index')}}");--}}
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

A font can be embedded only if it contains a setting by the font vendor that permits it to be embedded. Embedding prevents font substitution when readers view or print the file, and ensures that readers see the text in its original font. Embedding increases file size only slightly, unless the document uses CID fonts. a font format commonly used for Asian languages. You can embed or substitute fonts in Acrobat or when you export an InDesign document to PDF.

Please read the adobe [documentation](https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/using/pdf-fonts.html).

It is possible that the version you are using to do not be supported.